# 'Reply' & 'Reply to All' button missing from email message feed when using custom emailpublisher

Tags: publisher, casefeed

Hi i have a very simple email publisher to replace the original one :->

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
    <apex:emailPublisher entityId="{!case.id}"
        fromVisibility="selectable"
        subjectVisibility="readOnly"
        toVisibility="readOnly"
        fromAddresses="support@abc.com}"
        emailBody=""/>
</apex:page>
```

So i remove the standard 'Answer Customer' action and add in my custom emailpublisher in. Now all my email message record feed doesn't have the 'Reply' & 'Reply to All' button. What have i missed out? Basically what I want to achieve is I want the sender to default as our support email instead of user's personal email.

With Answer Customer Action

[image]

Without Answer Customer action (replaced with my custom email publisher)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on View Email link below, you will find the "**Reply**" or "**Reply All**" button. If you want those button to be displayed on the same case feed page as in standard behavior. I have raised an Idea with salesforce. You can vote there.

## IDEA Link

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBCiAAM

Thanks!
Sanjay Kumar